# php find one array values to another multidimensional array and if value not preset set zero

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays in PHP as follows,

Resultant array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [month] => Dec 2016
            [count] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [month] => Feb 2017
            [count] => 2
        )
)
```

Month Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Dec 2016
    [1] => Jan 2017
    [2] => Feb 2017
)
```

I am trying to merging this arrays so I can get below result,
but it's not happening. In this array, I using `array_search()` and `in_array()` for checking the array values is present in result array but not getting expected result. I want below output,

```
Array
(
    [Dec 2016] => 2
    [Jan 2017] => 0
    [Feb 2017] => 2
)
```

My code:

```
foreach ( $result_array as $val ) {
    $month = array_search ( $val ['month'], $monthArray );
    if ($val ['count'] == '' || $val ['count'] == 'NULL') {
        $countValue = 0;
    } else {
        $countValue = $val ['count'];
    }
    $final_array [] = $countValue;
}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: foreach ( $result_array as $val ) {

  $month = array_search ( $val ['month'], $monthArray );
  if ($val ['count'] == '' || $val ['count'] == 'NULL') {
   $countValue = 0;
  } else {
   $countValue = $val ['count'];
  }
   $final_array [] = $countValue;
 }

Comment: Put the in the question and format it properly. Use the "edit" link located below the question to update the question text any time you feel you can make it more clear (this way you increase your chances to get an useful answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that we have clean data:

```
    //turn months into keys    
    $months = array_flip($monthArray);

    // fill in the count values
    foreach($resultArray as $result) {
        $months[$result['month']] = $result['count'];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much Simas. This very useful for me.I am using this and array what I want.I am getting below array 
 (
             [Dec 2016] => 2
              [Jan 2017] => 1
              [Feb 2017] => 2
  )                                                                                                              see above array value set for Jan 2017 =1 but no count for Jan 2017.It should be 0.array 
 (
             [Dec 2016] => 2
              [Jan 2017] => 0
              [Feb 2017] => 2
  )

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
$result_array = array(
    array(
        'month' => 'Dec 2016',
        'count' => 2,
    ),
    array(
        'month' => 'Feb 2017',
        'count' => 2,
    )
);

$monthArray = array(
    'Dec 2016',
    'Jan 2017',
    'Feb 2017',
);



$final_array = array_combine($monthArray, array_fill(0, count($monthArray), 0));
foreach ($result_array as $item) {
    $mon = $item['month'];
    if (in_array($mon, $monthArray)) {
        $final_array[$mon] += $item['count'];
    }
}
print_r($final_array);
```

### How it works

It uses [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to create an array that associates `0` (zero) to the values in `$monthArray`. It basically turns the values in `$monthArray` to keys into a new array that has `0` as values.

Then it iterates over `$result_array` and for each item, if the value of `'month'` is in the output array then it simply add the value of `'count'` to the output.

The items having `'month'` values that are not present in the `$monthArray` array are not added to the output.

Comment: Thank u very much Axiac.